# Ratio & simultaneous linear equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, ratio

A pharmacist needs to combine a $2\%$ solution of a medication with a $25\%$ solution (of the SAME medication) to make $9$ litres of a $3\%$ solution.
Use simultaneous linear equations to determine how many litres of each solution she needs to mix.

Usually I would have an attempt and ask if I am on the right track, but my head is all over the place with this question.

Answer (score 1):

Let the initial volumes be $a$ and $b$:

$$\begin{cases}
a+b=9\\
0.02a+0.25b=0.03\times9=0.27
\end{cases}$$

Now you can try solving them.

Comment: I'm still lost from here sorry